# Ubuntu Touch HTML5 app Orientation lock

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

Can somebody tell me how can I fix my HTML 5 app into portrait mode only?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your *APP-NAME*.desktop file:

> X-Ubuntu-Supported-Orientations=portrait